# setting "$PATH" variables for PHP in AMPPS (OSX)

Tags: php, macos, ampps

I have a question about setting "$PATH" variables for PHP scripts in AMPPS
(On OSX 10.10 Yosemite).

The PHP in AMPPS seems to run as my user "danny", however the $PATH it sees
is different. Here's what I see from my terminal:
Dannys-MacBook-Air:AMPPS danny$ echo $PATH;
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

And here is what I get within a PHP script by printing out $_ENV:
["PATH"]=> string(29) "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin" ["USER"]=> string(5)
"danny"

I tried doing "putenv()", tried doing "shell_exec" with a different $PATH,
I tried doing SetEnv in .htaccess and in the Apache config file. I tried
editing the systemwide /etc/.bashrc , and my users ~/.bash_profile. Neither
helped so far.

All I need is to have /usr/local/bin as part of my $PATH.

Comment: Did you try to edit the file /etc/apache2/envvars ? (I'm running debian so the path may differ on OSX...)

Comment: Agree with @JuniusRendel. Doing `putenv()` etc. won't help you, you have to set the `PATH` before Apache starts. I ended up writing a small start script to modify the environment and then fire up my `/opt/local/apache2/bin/apachectl` (installed using MacPorts).

Comment: well, I tried adding ``export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin "`` in both of the files `/Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/envvars` and `/Applications/AMPPS/apache/bin/envvars-std` and I'm getting the same result again `["PATH"]=> string(29) "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an older post, but this helped me, (doing this with Ampps, not MAMP, but it should work the same)

From [here](http://www.ampps.com/wiki/Installing_Laravel_Framework)

Create a variable with the path to your PHP binary (in terminal)

they recommend

`export AMPPS_PHP=/Applications/AMPPS/php/bin`

mine was `export AMPPS_PHP=/Applications/AMPPS/php-7.1/bin`

then just

`export PATH="$AMPPS_PHP:$PATH"`

Test it out with `which php` or `php -v`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is even possible, but I wonder why do you need this, i.e. do you need really to change your PATH env variable? Or it would be enough to you using [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php) and setting the variabile only for the created process?

Comment: I'd prefer not to use this way as my production server won't work this way

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your **Apache Server** to run with your **credential** and resolve definitively the **$PATH** problem.
However, you can also do this and it should works :

```
<?php
putenv('PATH', getenv('PATH') . ';/usr/local/bin');
var_dump(getenv('PATH'));
?>
```

The modification of **$PATH** will still available only the duration of your **PHP** execution, there are other ways to set environment variable permanently

Hope that helps :)

Comment: as I said in my main question I tried both ways you just said and non of them doesn't work.

Comment: putenv() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in

Answer (score 0):

This may not be well received, but I have been in your spot and have come close to throwing my machine across the room trying to properly set the PHP path for MAMP in OSX.

I started using Vagrant and developing from a VM, and found it to be way easier, especially if you want to change languages for other projects. Trust me, it will save you time in the long run.

1. Download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
2. Download [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads)
3. Select what type of box you want via [PuPHPet](https://puphpet.com/)
4. `cd` into the puphpet directory and run `vagrant up` (may take a while!)

The inital setup will take a little bit of time, but be very fast moving forward and makes it really easy to share environments with others.

Cheers

EDIT: I think its a very real solution for the future, but for now what worked for me was adding: 
`export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH`  to my `.bash_profile`
on OSX Yosemite. I believe the folder structure changed in Yosemite.

Comment: Interesting, but it not a real solution.. must be a way to configure the $PATH some how.